3-stage rocket payload problem
A rocket goes to the sky, and undergoes 3 stages. I want to find the payload of it.
In stage 1, 80% of the mass is the fuel, 10% of the mass is dry mass, and 10% is the remaining rocket. Similarly, in Stage 2 and Stage 3, 80% of the mass is the fuel too in each stage, and 10% dry mass, 10% remaining rocket.
By Classical rocket equation, for each stage, speed gained is
$$
\Delta v = v_e\ln(\frac{100}{100-80})= v_e\ln5,
$$
and 3 stages in total, speed gained is:
$$
\Delta v =3v_e \ln 5=4.83v_e
$$
Hence the payload is 10%*10%*10%=0.1% of the initial mass $M_i$.
However, if I try to find payload in the following way:
$$
e^{\frac{-\Delta v}{v_e}}=\frac{M_f}{M_i},
$$
$$
e^{-4.83}\approx 0.08 = \frac{M_f}{M_i} \Rightarrow M_f=0.08M_i
$$
It says that payload is 8% of the initial mass.
I am confused, both statements seem right to me, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

The last two equations apply to a single stage rocket.
